# Did Police spray fake blood on themselves in Philadelphia on August 14th 2019?

Tags: united-states, police

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5VYWdILMRU) police officers sprayed fake blood on themselves in response to the [August 2019 Philadelphia shooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_2019_Philadelphia_shooting).

[image: Po po with drops of blood on the ground]

Is this account of the incident true?

Comment: As this just happened yesterday and is current event I am not sure this is on topic

Comment: Is there an official time limit for how long we should wait to be Skeptical about current events?

Comment: @chicks ask in [meta.skeptics.se]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[According to Truth Or Fiction](https://www.truthorfiction.com/does-video-show-police-spraying-fake-blood-on-themselves-during-a-philadelphia-shooting/)

> As for the liquid in the bottle, it is most likely a disinfecting solution such as Betadine (povidone-iodine, which can appear deep orange or red) or a treatment to hasten clotting pulled from what appears to be a belt trauma kit, hurriedly applied to an officer’s wounded arm while both men were standing behind a car door in order to protect themselves from bullets.